# Getting Invalid block type with custom extension

Tags: layout, extensions, blocks, template, magento-1

I have created a custom module so that I can call a block from a cms page.

```
{{block type="wpsync/getpostcontent" template="wpsync/getpostcontent.phtml" wpurl="http://localhost/about"}}
```

I am getting

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:

Can't see what I am doing wrong.

local/Elevated/Wpsync/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Elevated_Wpsync>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Elevated_Wpsync>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <getpostcontent>
                <class>Elevated_Wpsync_Block</class>
            </getpostcontent>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <getpostcontent>
                <class>Elevated_Wpsync_Model</class>
            </getpostcontent>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

local/Elevated/Wpsync/Block/Getpostcontent.php

```
<?php
class Elevated_Wpsync_Block_Getpostcontent extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function getPostContentFromUrl() {

        $url = $this->getData('wpurl');
        // call model to fetch data
        $pagecontent = Mage::getModel("wpsync/getpostcontent")->getPostContentFromUrl($url);

        return $pagecontent;
    }
}
```

local/Elevated/Wpsync/Model/Getpostcontent.php

```
<?php

class Elevated_Wpsync_Model_Getpostcontent extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    public function getPostContentFromUrl($url) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

app/etc/modules/Elevated_Wpsync.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Elevated_Wpsync>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Elevated_Wpsync>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/wpsync/getpostcontent.phtml

```
<?php
    echo $this->getPostContentFromUrl();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your **config.xml** to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Elevated_Wpsync>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Elevated_Wpsync>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <wpsync>
                <class>Elevated_Wpsync_Block</class>
            </wpsync>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <wpsync>
                <class>Elevated_Wpsync_Model</class>
            </wpsync>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks michael. I had done that last night after I noticed my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Michael's solution you can also replace:

```
{{block type="wpsync/getpostcontent" template="wpsync/getpostcontent.phtml" wpurl="http://localhost/about"}}
```

With

```
{{block type="getpostcontent/getpostcontent" template="wpsync/getpostcontent.phtml" wpurl="http://localhost/about"}}
```

Notice the change in the block type. The first part of the block type is defined by this in your `config.xml`

```
<blocks>
    <getpostcontent>
        <class>Elevated_Wpsync_Block</class>
    </getpostcontent>
</blocks>
```